InvalidArgumentException thrown with msg: The XCUITest driver only supports W3C actions execution in the native context
Gurus;
I am running the a MobileWeb test on Android and iOS one after another.
With Android, the default context is 'CHROMIUM' and it is running the entire test just fine whether I shifted to 'CHROMIUM' context or not. With iOS, even after shifting to WEBVIEW_1097.1 which is the WebView context name, I am facing the following error message org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: The XCUITest driver only supports W3C actions execution in the native context. when the below code was ran
actions.moveToElement(categoryElm).click(categoryElm).build().perform();
Basically, it is like moving to the Element 'categoryElm' and trying to click it, using the Actions class. I am not trying to do any gesture actions. What is the coding approach for this issue to be used to overcome ?
Titbits of code for reproducing the issue:---
WebElement categoryElm = waitingDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(String.format("//a[contains(text(),'%s')]",category))));
doWait(3000);
public Actions actions= = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(categoryElm).click(categoryElm).build().perform();

Reference: appium issue 1928
I am using the latest JDK 21, recent appium java-client 9.2.3, recent appium 2.11.2 on a mobile device with iOS version 17.6.1 on Mac version Sonama 14.6.1. Test being run on Safari browser
I have tried shifting to 'NATIVE' just before the click() code is being run with no use.
As per the suggestion in the issue#1928 I incorporated the looping in order to shift in to WEB_VIEW, and using SAFARI browser, as below,
This time the script could not go past the first web element locator, and failed doing it.
    /**
     * context switcher ==> https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/16481
     * In our case with iOS 17.6.1 real device, iOS webview is available by adding webviewConnectTimeout capability.    
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
        public void changeDriverContextToWeb() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("Android")) {
                Set<String> allContexts = ((AndroidDriver) driver).getContextHandles();//'Set' ensures non duplicate values
                System.out.println("Android allContexts = "+allContexts);
                for (String context : allContexts) {
                    if (context.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
                        System.out.println("Android allcontexts has WEBVIEW");
                        ((AndroidDriver) driver).context(context);
                    } // if
                } // for
        System.out.println("Current Android Context="+((SupportsContextSwitching)driver).getContext());
            } else {                 //"iOS"
                Integer loopCount = 1;
                while (loopCount < 10) { // looping ONLY for 'iOS' 
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep and hope the driver eventually pulls the webview context
                    Set<String> allContexts = ((IOSDriver) driver).getContextHandles();//Set ensures non duplicate values
                    System.out.println("iOS allContexts = "+loopCount+", "+allContexts);
                    for (String context : allContexts) {
                        if (context.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
                            System.out.println("iOS allcontexts has WEBVIEW");
                            ((IOSDriver) driver).context(context);
                            loopCount = 11;//exit 'while', once 'for' is done
                        } // if
                    } // for
         System.out.println("Current iOS Context="+loopCount+", "+((SupportsContextSwitching)driver).getContext());
                    loopCount++;
                } // while
            } // else
        }// method

I have to use this Actions class approach because other methods of click() such as WebElement.click(), JavascriptExecutor are not working for my page.

It works for me when using ExecuteScript instead of Actions.moveToElement as following:
WebDriver.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement)
Hope this can help you!
